# a parameter is missing. parameter ordinal = 1 dataAdapter

Tags: c#, windows-mobile-6, sql-server-ce-3.5

This is my code:

```
String client = textbox.text;
try {
    connexion.da = new SqlCeDataAdapter("Select NOM_PRENOM ,NUM_FAC_CLI ,SOLDE_RESTANT ,DATE_FACT ,MODE_PAIEMENT from EXP WHERE NOM_PRENOM_CLI=@client ", connexion.objConn);         
    connexion.da.Fill(ds, "EXPORT");
}
```

I can't find a property `da.Parameters.add("@client", client)`.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What errors are you getting? Have you defined your parameters somewhere? We need to see more

Comment: thanks for your interaction ,the answer is below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can add parameters like this

da.SelectCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
da.SelectCommand.Parameters.Add("@client", client);